# Calculate Median with SQL (DB2)

Tags: sql, db2, aggregate-functions, median

I'm having issues calculating the median for my result set and could use some help.  I need to provide the median, max, min, avg, and standard deviation. There are 222 rows which can be more or less and I'm not sure what I have so far is an accurate way of calculating the median.  Here is my query.

```
    Select 
    min(nodes) as min_nodes
    ,max(nodes) as max_nodes
    ,avg(nodes) as avg_nodes
    ,max(nodes) + min(nodes))/2 as median_nodes
    ,stddev(nodes) as sd_nodes
    from Table
```

Comment: unless db2 has a median function built in, you'll have to it in multiple steps: get number of rows in result set, figure out the mid-point, and there's your median.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to calculate the median:

```
select avg(nodes)
from (
    select nodes
         , row_number() over(order by nodes asc) as rn1
         , row_number() over(order by nodes desc) as rn2
    from table
) as x(nodes, rn1, rn2)
where rn1 in (rn2, rn2 - 1, rn2 + 1)
```

Enumerating the nodes in both directions is an optimization.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using window functions:

```
Select min(nodes) as min_nodes, max(nodes) as max_nodes, avg(nodes) as avg_nodes,
       avg(case when 2*seqnum in (cnt, cnt - 1, cnt + 1) then nodes end) as median_nodes,
       stddev(nodes) as sd_nodes
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by nodes) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
```

The use of `avg()` is to handle the case where you have an even number of values.  In this case, the median is traditionally assigned to the midpoint of the two middle values.